# sum up all the time delta values in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, sum, timedelta

I have a dictionary with time delta values.

```
{1: Timedelta('0 days 01:44:39'),
 2: Timedelta('0 days 02:34:01'),
 3: Timedelta('0 days 00:49:15'),
 4: Timedelta('0 days 01:13:26'),
 5: Timedelta('0 days 00:38:14')}
```

I want to sum up all the values and show a total timestamp (addition of all the time stamps) as an output. any idea how to achieve this requirement?

I tried converting it into list and then used sum() function but they didn't work with timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert dictionary to `Series`, so possible use `sum` of timedeltas which exclude `None`, `NaN` by default:

```
d = {1: pd.Timedelta('0 days 01:44:39'),
 2: pd.Timedelta('0 days 02:34:01'),
 3: pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:49:15'),
 4: pd.Timedelta('0 days 01:13:26'),
 5: pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:38:14')}

s = pd.Series(d)
print (s.sum())
0 days 06:59:35
```

Comment: oh my god. Thanks a lot. I am learning a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> sum(iterable, start)
> iterable : iterable can be anything list , tuples or dictionaries ,
> but most importantly it should be **numbers.**

> start : this start is added to the sum of
> numbers in the iterable.

From above you can say `sum` function works on `numbers` only.

To make it work with `timedeltas` use Python's `datetime` module. Do below:

```
In [804]: d = {1: Timedelta('0 days 01:44:39'),
     ...:  2: Timedelta('0 days 02:34:01'),
     ...:  3: Timedelta('0 days 00:49:15'),
     ...:  4: Timedelta('0 days 01:13:26'),
     ...:  5: Timedelta('0 days 00:38:14')}

In [805]: import datetime

In [803]: sum(d.values(), datetime.timedelta())
Out[803]: Timedelta('0 days 06:59:35')
```

Time performance of all answers for small dataset:

@jezrael's answer:

```
In [806]: def j():
     ...:     s = pd.Series(d)
     ...:     return s.sum()
     ...: 

In [807]: %timeit j()
491 µs ± 86.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@Pablo's answer:

```
In [810]: %timeit reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, d.values())
22.7 µs ± 250 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

@my answer:

```
In [808]: %timeit sum(d.values(), datetime.timedelta())
31.9 µs ± 451 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: @JSVJ Have posted some time performances for all answers. `Series` answer performs the worst.

Comment: thanks @MayankPorwal

I am getting NaT . Could you please help me here ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Can you add performance for 1k, 10k rows rows?

Comment: @jezrael Sure. Please wait. adding.

Comment: Pandas does not perform the worst in summing up the rows, but creating the Series has a lot of overhead relatively speaking. Either exclude it from the benchmark or use more rows and Pandas will be faster by a lot.

Comment: @JulianWgs - yop, I think problem here is compare only few values. Also compare remove missing values and then see difference, pandas wins.

Comment: Yes, pandas might win when the rows are a lot. Let's wait for OP to comeback with what kind of dataset is he working on. Not best to use pandas for small datasets I guess.

Comment: @jezrael Done. Please check.

Comment: I am working on a dataset with more than 100,000+ rows. Pandas works good. Thanks a lot for this knowledge and effort. @MayankPorwal

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?#functools.reduce):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> d = {1: pd.Timedelta('0 days 01:44:39'),
 2: pd.Timedelta('0 days 02:34:01'),
 3: pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:49:15'),
 4: pd.Timedelta('0 days 01:13:26'),
 5: pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:38:14')}
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, d.values())
#Timedelta('0 days 06:59:35')
```

Comment: Reduce is not recommended by the former Python BDFL Guido van Rossum and Im not a fan either. It can almost always be avoided by a list comprehension or a small loop.

Comment: @JulianWgs I understand it is not recommended in non-trivial cases, which is not the case here